# FloatingActionButton elevation not working on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, elevation

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical">
> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>     android:minHeight="56dp"
>     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
>     app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle" >
> </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
>     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>         android:id="@+id/myFAB"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>         android:clickable="true"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>         android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_star"
>         app:borderWidth="0dp"
>         app:elevation="10dp"
>         />
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:id="@+id/relative6"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>     </RelativeLayout>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_below="@id/relative6"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>         <ListView
>             android:id="@+id/list_history"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="0dip"
>             android:layout_gravity="start"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:clickable="false"
>             android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
>             android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
>             android:divider="@null"
>             android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
>     </LinearLayout>
> </RelativeLayout>
>  </LinearLayout>
> ```

Thats my xml, the elevation is not working for pre-lollipop devices.

Works perfectly for new devices nexus 5, 6 i tested them.

But did not work on old device running kit kat.

Thank you very much  for any help, and fruitful information.

Comment: add this line to your code app:fabSize="normal"

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting `app:borderWidth="0dp"` resolve this issues for me.

**Note:** don't forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your root layout.

its working for me

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/your_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/floating_button_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/floating_button_margin_right"
        app:elevation="@dimen/floating_button_elevation"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/your_ripple_color"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/your_bg_color" />
```

Comment: it doesnt solve for me, i have already done that. check my code.

Comment: the floatingbutton is still under my listview

Comment: try changing your parent layout to **RelativeLayout**

Comment: makes no difference.

Comment: Try adding `app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"` @krikorHerlopian to the properties of the `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: the solution was moving the part of floatingactionbutton code, under my listview code.

Comment: yes @krikorHerlopian thats what i tried to explain when i asked about working with **RelativeLayout**